# How many String objects are created

Tags: java, string

I was looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497335/how-many-objects-are-created-in-the-following-strings-in-java)

In Java - How many string objects would  be created in the following two scenarios?

```
String s1 = "Java";
String s2 = new String("Java");
```

and

```
String s1 = new String("Java");
String s2 = "Java";
```

Trying to wrap my head around Permgen string pools - I assumed there will always be two objects in both cases, One in the permgen pool and one in the heap, the one in the heap pointing to the reference in the string pool! Is this not correct?