# How may String Objects are created in java (By the following code)

Tags: java, string, string-pool

How many String objects are created in java by the following code: 
if there is  no String object in the String pool containing the same value .
(I read [somewhere](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/top-20-core-java-interview-questions.html) that **Since we are passing arguments as "Hello", which is a String literal, it will also create another object as "Hello" on string pool**. )

```
String s="Hello";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many Java objects are generated by this - new String("abcd")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192574/how-many-java-objects-are-generated-by-this-new-stringabcd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one object will be created in the string constant pool. Reason behind is while we creating the object,we didn't use any "new" keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Only one [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) [literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Concepts.doc.html#20359) will be created in the String constant Pool.

Answer (score 3):

No object is created but rather value is inserted in String pool if it is inserted before

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate between literals which are loaded to the string pool when the class is loaded and passed around (this is your case) and the case of creating a string object by actually parsing/reading/constructing something.

The later case is of course much more often happening in programs, and it will always generate a new String object (even when the string value itself is already in the string pool).

See also [Will the String passed from outside the java application be saved in String pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185934/will-the-string-passed-from-outside-the-java-application-be-saved-in-string-pool/25224697#25224697)

Answer (score -1):

One String Object (Literals are also Objects) is created IF "Hello" is NOT already present in the String pool.

Comment: But it is present. The compiler and class loader put it there, before the statement was executed.

Comment: @EJP - I said that it will be created if it is not present. Which means that it will not be created and added in String constants pool if it is present